React Native Dynamic Statusbar
In React Native Is There Any Way To Change The Statusbar Dynamically? Suppose I set My Statusbar To Light Then If I Go To Another Screen And Comes Back Then The Statusbar Do Not Changes To Light. Can I Change This?
I Tried To Change The Statusbar to Light But That Not Happened. I Want To Change The Statusbar Dynamically.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
